# Flutter : How to store 'Favorited List' using shared_preference

Tags: android, flutter

This problem is about how to keep the favorited item in the List, even after I re-open the app.

I want to keep the favorited item in doaList into favDoa, even after I close my app and re-open it. I've seen about the shared_preference package in flutter to store data, but i confused how can i implement it into my app. Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:json_test/class/doa.dart';
import 'package:json_test/page/DoaPage.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List<Doa> doaList;
  List<Doa> favDoa;
  bool _isInit = true;

  Future<void> fetchDoa(BuildContext context) async {
    final jsonstring =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/doa.json');
    doaList = doaFromJson(jsonstring);
    _isInit = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("JSON Data test"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _isInit ? fetchDoa(context) : Future(null),
                builder: (context, _) {
                  if (doaList.isNotEmpty) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: doaList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Doa doa = doaList[index];
                        return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(doa.judul),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          DoaPage(
                                            doa: doa,
                                          )));
                                },
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    doa.fav
                                        ? Icons.favorite
                                        : Icons.favorite_border,
                                    color: doa.fav ? Colors.red : null,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                                    doa.fav = !doa.fav;
                                  }),
                                )));
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                })));
  }
}
```

when I click the favorite icon in the list, it will be marked ***true*** in the "doa.fav". How can I implement the shared_preference package in my code to keep the doa.fav's data? Thank you so much for your answer :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a list of integer to store the Doa Ids, say you name it `favoriteList`
2. Each time you click the favorite button, add the Doa's id to `favoriteList`. Also save it to shared_preferences. It only support list of string, so you need to convert it first, something like:

```
List<String> stringFavoriteIds =
      favoriteList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
  SharedPrefs().favoriteIds = stringFavoriteIds ;
```

3. Next, each time you open the app, load `SharedPrefs().favoriteIds` to `favoriteList`
4. Compare the Doa Ids in `favoriteList` to your list of doa to mark Doa.fav to true for matching Ids.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Jimmy for your answer. I'll try your advices. Hope u always health !

Comment: I found error while inserting your code :( . Let i describe it in answer column below